# Constructing an embedding and describing complex conjugation using $\varphi$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

I am trying to construct an embedding $\varphi:\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})\to\mathbb{C}$, where $\zeta_{p}$ is the $p$-th root of unity. I then need to describe complex conjugation as an element of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})$ using the inclusion $\varphi$. I don't even know where to start.

My specific example is where $p=5$, but the general case would be very helpful.

Comment: Complex conjugation sends $\zeta$ to $1/\zeta$. Does this help?

Comment: Possibly. The `embedding' is complex conjugation then?

The Galois group $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$ yes? So I am trying to describe complex conjugation as an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{4}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, say your field is $K=\Bbb Q(\zeta)$, where $\zeta$ is a *chosen* primitive $n$-th root of unity, maybe if $n=5$ you choose $\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)$. Then if you’re embedding into $\Bbb C$, you must sent $\zeta$ to a primitive $n$-th root of unity: if $n=5$, there are four of these; in general, there are $\phi(n)$ primitive $n$-th roots of unity. And you check that every such root determines the embedding completely. Finally, you check that sending $\zeta$ to $1/\zeta$ determines an embedding that agrees with complex conjugation on $K$. (Only on $K$, mind you: this embedding is not defined on all of $\Bbb C$, so it’s not quite right to ask for your embedding to “be” complex conjugation.)

Comment: Thank you. 

Do you mean $\cos(2\pi/5)+i\sin(2\pi/5)$?

So the embedding is $\varphi:K\to\mathbb{C}$, $\zeta\mapsto\zeta^{-1}$?
Checking: $\varphi(\zeta_{1})=\zeta_{1}^{-1}=\zeta_{4}$, $\varphi(\zeta_{2})=\zeta_{2}^{-1}=\zeta_{3}$, $\varphi(\zeta_{3})=\zeta_{3}^{-1}=\zeta_{2}$, and $\varphi(\zeta_{4})=\zeta_{4}^{-1}=\zeta_{1}$. This determines completely the embedding?

How do I formally check that this agrees with complex conjugation on $K$?

Comment: Yes, of course! I’ll correct it pronto. It agrees with conjugation on $K$ because it agrees with conjugation on your $\Bbb Q$-basis of $K$.

Comment: Ok, sorry - still a little confused... So as part of $\text{Gal}(\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_{p})/\mathbb{Q})\cong\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}=\{0,1,2,3\}$, complex conjugation is what? I think that it should be $2$, but I;m not sure if that's right.

Comment: You should think of the G-group as a subgroup of $(\Bbb Z/(5))^\times$, the nonzero elements of the ring of integers modulo $5$. Then the group is $\{1,2,3,4\}$, and conjugation is $4=-1$.

Comment: Aha! Ok, that makes a lot of sense. I thought it must be $4$ originally but then that made no sense in $\mathbb{Z}/4\mathbb{Z}$. You are truly a wonderful person.